# how to start influxdb 2.0.2?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

ok I installed (in ubuntu 20.04) as it said the official page of influxdb https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads/, specifically these commands:

```
wget https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb_2.0.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i influxdb_2.0.2_amd64.deb
```

then add commands to start and create persistence with the daemon.

```
systemctl enable --now influxdb
systemctl status influxdb
```

and it comes out as if it was activated and running normally

```
● influxdb.service - InfluxDB is an open-source, distributed, time series database
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/influxdb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-11-20 17:43:54 -03; 55min ago
       Docs: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/
   Main PID: 750 (influxd)
      Tasks: 7 (limit: 1067)
     Memory: 33.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/influxdb.service
             └─750 /usr/bin/influxd
Nov 20 17:44:03 hypercc influxd[750]: ts=2020-11-20T20:44:03.754479Z lvl=info msg="Open store (start)" log_id=0QarEkHl000 service=storage-engine op_name=tsdb_open op_event=start
Nov 20 17:44:03 hypercc influxd[750]: ts=2020-11-20T20:44:03.754575Z lvl=info msg="Open store (end)" log_id=0QarEkHl000 service=storage-engine op_name=tsdb_open op_event=end op_elapsed=0.098ms
Nov 20 17:44:03 hypercc influxd[750]: ts=2020-11-20T20:44:03.754661Z lvl=info msg="Starting retention policy enforcement service" log_id=0QarEkHl000 service=retention check_interval=30m
Nov 20 17:44:03 hypercc influxd[750]: ts=2020-11-20T20:44:03.754888Z lvl=info msg="Starting precreation service" log_id=0QarEkHl000 service=shard-precreation check_interval=10m advance_period=30m
Nov 20 17:44:03 hypercc influxd[750]: ts=2020-11-20T20:44:03.755164Z lvl=info msg="Starting query controller" log_id=0QarEkHl000 service=storage-reads concurrency_quota=10 initial_memory_bytes_quota_per_query=9223372036854775807 memory_bytes_quota_per_query=9223372036854775807 max_memory_bytes=0 queue_size=10
Nov 20 17:44:03 hypercc influxd[750]: ts=2020-11-20T20:44:03.755725Z lvl=info msg="Configuring InfluxQL statement executor (zeros indicate unlimited)." log_id=0QarEkHl000 max_select_point=0 max_select_series=0 max_select_buckets=0
Nov 20 17:44:04 hypercc influxd[750]: ts=2020-11-20T20:44:04.071001Z lvl=info msg=Starting log_id=0QarEkHl000 service=telemetry interval=8h
Nov 20 17:44:04 hypercc influxd[750]: ts=2020-11-20T20:44:04.071525Z lvl=info msg=Listening log_id=0QarEkHl000 transport=http addr=:8086 port=8086
Nov 20 18:14:03 hypercc influxd[750]: ts=2020-11-20T21:14:03.757182Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (start)" log_id=0QarEkHl000 service=retention op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=start
Nov 20 18:14:03 hypercc influxd[750]: ts=2020-11-20T21:14:03.757233Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (end)" log_id=0QarEkHl000 service=retention op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=end op_elapsed=0.074ms
```

What should I add to be able to write "influx" and go directly to the DB to make queries? is it something with the ip address?

When I enter influx, I only get help options but it doesn't say anything about connecting or something like that.

by the way here https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/get-started/ it is installed in a different way but it is supposed that both ways work well.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually tools like `Telegraf` are used to collect data and write it to InfluxDB. You can install Telegraf on each server you want to collect data from.
https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.17/

You can browse to `http://your_server_ip:8086` and login to chronograf (included to InfluxDB 2.0). Here you can create dashboards and query data from InfluxDB.

Its also possible to do manual queries via the InfluxDB CLI. You can simply use it with the `influx query` command in your terminal.
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/query-data/

Note that some commands need authentication before you are allowed to execute them (e.g. the user command). You can authenticate by adding the `-t` parameter followed by a valid user token (can be found in the web interface).
Example: `influx -t token_here user list`

Hope this helps you out.